# Forcing Julius to regenerate for each request

Tags: yesod

I am trying to post a form using Ajax and I generate the URL string in the request based on the route. Like so:

```
    $.ajax ({ type: "POST",
      url: "@{MyHandlerR objectId}",
      headers: {
          Accept:         "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      },
      ...
```

When I go to /path/1, the url is set properly to /newpath/1 in the above Javascript code. However, when I go to /path/2 next, the javascript does not get regenerated and as a consequence the path remains the same /newpath/1.

Is there a way to force a regeneration of the Julius file? As a work around, I can just grab the url from the html page but want to know if there is a better way to deal with this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug that was resolved in shakespeare-js 1.1.4.1. Can you try upgrading and see if that solves your problem?

Comment: Hi Michael, by upgrade you mean, remove yesod and reinstall or just run cabal update and cabal install --force-reinstalls? I did the latter and it did not change the output. I am using the standard scaffolded site with this line: shakespeare-js >= 1.0.2 && < 1.2. How do I find what version of shakespeare-js I have?

Comment: Best thing to do is to change your cabal file to have a shakespeare-js minimum bound of 1.1.4.1, then run `cabal install --force-reinstalls` in your project.

Comment: When I change the min bound, Yesod does not launch -- I get <code>     cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing:
shakespeare-js >=1.1.4.1 && <1.2 </code>. I changed the cabal file, ran <code>cabal install --force-reinstalls</code>. If I set the min bound to 1.1.4, it launches fine but the original issue still remains.

Comment: I did that before but forgot to mention it. I tried again after running `cabal update` and still get the same error message saying 1.1.4.1 missing.

Comment: I have a similar problem and it didn't help to upgrade to shakespeare-js 1.1.4.1. Any other things we could check? I will update the complete yesod installation to the newest version now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and updating to shakespeare-js 1.1.4.1 as Michael suggested didn't help. However, I kept updating some more yesod packages and now it works. Here is the complete dependency list for my project with working recompilation of julius templates at every request:

```
    Dependencies:  HTTP-4000.2.5-28d9701af6cb2d10d5070cbf6ed47a59,
               aeson-0.6.1.0-cde7af829bbea3ac827694aa2510a102,
               attoparsec-0.10.4.0-c391286d724823eaea3d4278acc0acc0,
               base-4.5.1.0-66f22db3dfcd87541c9c7e50e7095d26,
               blaze-html-0.6.1.1-5eb00422be0277775590b4b29ad45e2d,
               bytestring-0.9.2.1-503e91bb155301fdb1956cb5c26ce6e9,
               conduit-1.0.7.1-0511660e512a3cec04b33c5b7f2daf7d,
               containers-0.4.2.1-75f143aa39a3e77a1ce2300025bdd8ce,
               data-default-0.5.3-f33230611d35c41f344389ab4c476cef,
               deepseq-1.3.0.0-c26e15897417ecd448742528253d68f6,
               directory-1.1.0.2-90bfc47dbd5ac1313aec9ce76cc22338,
               either-3.4.1-ca49211a7bff3ee6dad5964300774fcb,
               enumerator-0.4.19-691bfc79b1307f260c3bed7c660ca787,
               errors-1.4.2-38b5cc57662a4d7758cb0b7a98e5e95d,
               fast-logger-0.3.1-b31c6f4545741767ef9f0c1e7aabb95e,
               hamlet-1.1.7.2-3b72b7ddc47a000199206c749f99daa2,
               hjsmin-0.1.4.1-8d8e0263b0d13644d39a144b315f013a,
               http-conduit-1.9.4.1-a32be4840c47c665bdc8200d735b893a,
               http-types-0.8.0-abf1cc745dc88f49ff33fda44d95c935,
               mime-mail-0.4.2-1a1836fcf5a352b8c5067c2fbefa5724,
               monad-control-0.3.2.1-325c196d0e82ae0923fc262c7eb5203d,
               monad-logger-0.3.1.1-70025dd5d4d9f30a2c319311fc1ec3bd,
               mtl-2.1.2-02e701f9b1590ee88a0b5b0bd5d93a29,
               network-2.3.1.0-efa1c7220c576804829351b700849052,
               old-locale-1.0.0.4-5e45cabd3b4fdcad9e353ea3845f5ef7,
               persistent-1.2.1.1-d16c0d7db2515b5e51bb89a0a5433a18,
               persistent-postgresql-1.2.1-56f1e8c317aef2e3d1e3bd0810347412,
               persistent-template-1.2.0.2-49786c54b7c951e49542bdc0d39701fb,
               regex-posix-0.95.2-417a70abf4122fdc399910fd04439ecf,
               safe-0.3.3-2e88224aa98500bc4dcbbdfb58ba6a17,
               semigroups-0.9.2-c48ab2744f6565641b443c955b76d44a,
               shakespeare-css-1.0.6.3-4a394d9b2a18d7c964cebd070ad5cbb1,
               shakespeare-js-1.2.0-81b96be286c5d969c9de5482d85833ca,
               shakespeare-text-1.0.0.7-47944e312bdeaf894287cd643ad6847a,
               shelly-0.15.4-e747484ce18c0ac32c90b75094585c4a,
               statistics-0.10.2.0-b106f61bbe0b7932af82166a17322bb1,
               statistics-linreg-0.2.3-7b846159150793fda8df72a61d5001c1,
               template-haskell-2.7.0.0-ea0103105685f73dfd311f959f3ec5a5,
               text-0.11.2.3-db61832d0c4660614c4ceff234ed4abb,
               time-1.4-d61e2caaa0486655b4e141dc277ed49f,
               timezone-olson-0.1.2-960d8681a104c77e1f332052889a5d4b,
               timezone-series-0.1.2-e065f94ccc32d05a0523bd76236bf2d2,
               vector-0.10.0.1-3450daae3d9f2092020075d05481123c,
               wai-extra-1.3.4.2-be3d9d5535ba845aa5d00d77a2741583,
               warp-1.3.9-b3d12eb3e1e49c3caa7df53ab3975ece,
               xml-1.3.12-ff3424b78e3e19078e5d410d6cd49c60,
               yaml-0.8.3-c6a9d3a303a1ae9b01903ad3831cfcb9,
               yesod-1.2.2.1-0504dfba238cb1072923a349a994f5e4,
               yesod-auth-1.2.3-16d2d9be37fa167a7b64e182579ad640,
               yesod-core-1.2.4.3-b960ca223bbb7b1e47ef3698e4c90141,
               yesod-form-1.3.2.2-6890d228f722c380dc5bb1d599a8d584,
               yesod-static-1.2.0.1-338a66214147e472ce3d0e7db90e1175
```

Addendum: Here are the dependencies from my cabal file:

```
build-depends: base                          >= 4          && < 5
             --, yesod-platform                >= 1.2        && < 1.3
             , yesod                         >= 1.2        && < 1.3
             , yesod-core                    >= 1.2        && < 1.3
             , yesod-auth                    >= 1.2        && < 1.3
             , yesod-static                  >= 1.2        && < 1.3
             , yesod-form                    >= 1.3        && < 1.4
             , bytestring                    >= 0.9        && < 0.11
             , text                          >= 0.11       && < 0.12
             , persistent                    >= 1.2        && < 1.3
             , persistent-postgresql         >= 1.2        && < 1.3
             , persistent-template           >= 1.2        && < 1.3
             , template-haskell
             , hamlet                        >= 1.1        && < 1.2
             , shakespeare-css               >= 1.0.6.3    && < 1.1
             , shakespeare-js                >= 1.2.0      && < 1.3
             , shakespeare-text              >= 1.0        && < 1.1
             , hjsmin                        >= 0.1.4      && < 0.2
             , monad-control                 >= 0.3        && < 0.4
             , wai-extra                     >= 1.3        && < 1.4
             , yaml                          >= 0.8        && < 0.9
             , http-conduit                  >= 1.9        && < 1.10
             , directory                     >= 1.1        && < 1.3
             , warp                          >= 1.3        && < 1.4
             , data-default
             , aeson
             , conduit                       >= 1.0
             , monad-logger                  >= 0.3
             , fast-logger                   >= 0.3
```

Update dependency versions and do `cabal update` and `cabal install --force-reinstalls` and it should work.